# How to execute gql and get result using db.Model approach?

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

```
class Group(db.Model):
    group = db.StringProperty()    
...    
qResult = Group.gql( 'WHERE group=test').get()
self.response.out.write(qResult)
```

I have got error "BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE condition at symbol "...
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
qResult = Group.gql('WHERE group=:1', 'test').get()
```

You should also be aware that qResult will be a Group object. What you may be looking to return is the 'group' attribute.

```
self.response.out.write(qResult.group)
```